# How can I put the port and host in the property file in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this url

```
private static final String PRODUCTS_URL = "http://localhost:3007/catalog/products/";
```

And this methods:

```
public JSONObject getProductByIdFromMicroservice(String id) throws IOException, JSONException {
        return getProductsFromProductMicroservice(PRODUCTS_URL + id);
    }

    public JSONObject getProductsFromProductMicroservice(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        CloseableHttpClient productClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet getProducts = new HttpGet(url);

        CloseableHttpResponse microserviceResponse = productClient.execute(getProducts);
        HttpEntity entity = microserviceResponse.getEntity();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((entity.getContent())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        br.close();

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        System.out.println(obj);

        return obj;
    }
```

I want to put the port and host in a separate property file. I have already seen examples using properties and the yml file. But I do not understand how then my methods will work using this port when creating an instance of the class, which I will indicate in the properties file. Can you tell?

Comment: Look up the `@Value` annotation, you need to inject that as an annotation to the property of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your properties in a properties file in the resource directory for example

```
PRODUCTS_URL="http://localhost:3007/catalog/products/"
```

and add `@PropertySource("YOUR_RESOURCE_FILE_HERE.properties")` in your main class (`Application.java`)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("products.properties")
public class Application {...}
```

and then use `@Value("${YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME}")` to load it:

```
@Value("${PRODUCTS_URL}")
private String PRODUCTS_URL;
```

Check this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Comment: +1 for this.  Using the @Value annotation instead of getting the value using the Spring environment would better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it :

CONFIG FILE

```
#Database Server Properties
dbUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Something;
dbUser=sa
dbPassword=SomePassword
```

Then i annotate a config class with this :

```
@PropertySource("file:${ENV_VARIABLE_TO_PATH}/config.properties")
```

Then autowire this field :

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

Then create the data source :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() 
{
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

    try
    {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(100);

        String dbUrl = environment.getProperty("dbUrl");

        if (dbUrl != null)
        {
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException("The dbUrl property is missing from the config file!");
        }

        String dbUser = environment.getProperty("dbUser");

        if (dbUser != null)
        {
            dataSource.setUsername(dbUser);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException("The dbUser property is missing from the config file!");
        }

        String dbPassword = environment.getProperty("dbPassword");

        if (dbPassword != null)
        {
            dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException("The dbPassword property is missing from the config file!");
        }

        logger.debug("Successfully initialized datasource");
    }
    catch (PropertyNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        logger.fatal("Error initializing datasource : " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    return dataSource;
}
```

I know this is not exactly your scenario but perhaps you can find inspiration from this code to suit your specific needs?

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here mention using `@PropertySource` annotation to specify path of config files. Also if this is a test code (unit/integration) you can also make use of another annotation `@TestPropertySource`.

With this, we can define configuration sources that have higher precedence than any other source used in the project.

See here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source